# Automatically include a listing of all files in a folder

Tags: automation, matlab-prettifier

My thesis supervisor requires me to include all my MATLAB code in the PDF. My code is scattered in a dozen `.m` files, all in the same folder.

I know I can include code, using the `matlab-prettifier` package, and I do so as follows:

```
\lstinputlisting[style=Matlab-editor]{codice/ICCplot.m}
```

In essence, I want to do the following:

```
for \filename in codice/*.m
    \section{\filename}
    \lstinputlisting[style=Matlab-editor]{codice/\filename.m}
end for
```

Comment: A dozen is 12, right? Unless the filenames are very complicated I would suggest to do this manually, just copy-paste it 12 times and change the filenames. Otherwise you can use a scripting language of your choice (for example MATLAB itself) to produce the 2*12 lines of LaTeX code with the correct filenames automatically, and copy the resulting code to your document.

Comment: I would have liked the freedom to rename, add, remove files without worrying about having to run a separate tool. Oh well. I guess I could write a Bahs script and find a way to have it run before every compilation.

Comment: Write yourself a Makefile, call LaTeX with that Makefile, add some wildcard matching to your Makefile to pass the list of files to LaTeX.

Comment: Yes, thanks. Do I have to mark my question as duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this with a Makefile, a very simple one is the:

```
TEX=pdflatex
NAME=riccardos_thesis
MFILES=$(wildcard codice/*.m)

all: $(NAME).pdf

$(NAME).pdf: $(NAME).tex $(MFILES)
    $(TEX) -jobname="$(NAME)" "\def\RiccardosMFiles{$(MFILES)}\input{$(NAME).tex}"
```

Together with this main TeX file:

```tex
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{matlab-prettifier}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\showallmfiles{}
  {
    \exp_args:NNno \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { codice/ } \RiccardosMFiles
    \seq_pop_left:NN \l_tmpa_seq \l_tmpa_tl
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq
      {
        \section{##1}
        \lstinputlisting[style=Matlab-editor]{codice/##1}
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\showallmfiles
\end{document}
```